# Change Cinnamon Panel Icons

Tags: icons, panel, cinnamon

I recently installed Cinnamon and noticed that as I change the GTK, Cinnamon and icon themes, the panel icons remained the same. How can I change them to match my icon themes?

[image]

Note that the battery icon is not part of my icon theme, it was like that from the start.

Comment: Cinnamon is neither created nor supported by Ubuntu developers or Canonical. you may find support from their respective launchpad page or from Linux-mint website.

Comment: Cinnamon that is installed from the launchpad PPA is On-Topic for Ask Ubuntu - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3265/should-questions-related-to-cinnamon-desktop-environment-be-answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out that the applets use different icons than what comes in an icon theme. It says what the icon is in it's applet.js file. It's easy to find it, open the file and search for "icon-name" or "icon_name" and you should be able to find it.
These usually have "symbolic" in their name. These are also the same icons that are used in Gnome-Shell's panel

Answer (score 0):

Also you can change the size of the panel applets icons in the **cinnamon.css** theme file, to make it consistent. Not exactly as required, but could do the trick.

Search for the "**Applets (applet.js)**" section and add this line:

```
.applet-icon {
color: white;    /* or wathever you like */
icon-size: 22px; /* adjust applet icon size */ }
```